# Why a rotation about $\frac{\pi}{2}$ doesn't have eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm reading **Apostol's**: *Calculus, Vol.2*:

There is an exercise in which he argues that a rotation about $\cfrac{\pi}{2}$ in the plane doesn't have eigenvectors (but applying the transformation twice does have). I'm confused, how no? Assume I didn't screw everything up, If I get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-1 \\
1  & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\lambda I \quad \quad \quad \begin{bmatrix}
0 &-1 \\
1  & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}-\lambda I=0 \quad \quad \quad \begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda &-1 \\
1  & -\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}=0 $$

And then:

$$\det \begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda &-1 \\
1  & -\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}=0 \quad \quad \quad \lambda+1=0 \quad \quad \quad \lambda = -1$$

With this, I guess the eigenvector should be:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0  & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, negating that I didn't screw everything up, I must have screwed something up but I can't figure out what was it.

Comment: Did you notice that your vector is not a vector but a matrix.

Comment: If you work in $\mathbf C^2$, it has (complex) eigenvectors. Eigenvalues are guaranteed to exist only in algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @Fabian I don't get it. Shouldn't we use the transformation (which is represented by the matrix) instead of the vector?

Comment: Your notation is sloppy and doesn't make sense from the first line. Two matrices are equal if each of their elements are equal. $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix} = \lambda I$ will never be true for any $\lambda$.

Comment: @JessicaK Yes. I did it algorithmically and didn't pay attention to the actual thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well if you rotate by $90^\circ$ no nonzero real vector can become a scalar multiple of itself. However, if you rotate by $180^\circ$, everything is multiplied by $-1$.

Answer (score 5):

The determinant is $\lambda^2+1$.

Comment: Yes! I knew I couldn't assume I didn't screw everything up.

Answer (score 1):

> I must have screwed something up but I can't figure out what was it.

It is about the carless notations. First of all, denote the rotation about $\pi/2$ as
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-1 \\
1  & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The three identities in the beginning of your post do not make any sense. 
You could have written down
$$
Av=\lambda v,\quad (A-\lambda I)v=0,\quad\det(A-\lambda I)=0.
$$

What you want is showing that
$$
\det(A-\lambda I)=0,\tag{1}
$$
has no *real root* for (1).

Comment: I'm confused about one thing: The $x$ should be a vector, isn't it? So how can we speak about the identity of $x$?

Comment: which part are you referring to in my answer?

Comment: Nevermind, I understood what I had messed. $A$ is the transformation acting on $v$ and then we can write 

$$Av=\lambda v \\ Av=\lambda I v  \\ Av-\lambda I v=0 \\ (A-\lambda I)v=0$$

I was messing up things in my head because I hadn't done this development.